# How to add features to a PostGIS layer using Quantum GIS?

Tags: postgis, qgis

I am using Quantum GIS and the PostGIS dbms. I am able to call the PostGIS layer into QGIS but i am unable to add feature to it. I am using the method of adding features to a Shapefile but still it is not getting reflected in the layer, and I don't know how to save it to the PostGIS database if I am able to add the feature to the PostGIS layer.

I may not have used some technical term for this problem because i don't know what to call it, I am expressing the problem in my own terms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general workflow looks like this:

If you don't have a suitable PostGIS table yet, use PostGIS Manager - Create Table to start one.

[image]

Then:

1. Load the PostGIS table into the project.
2. Enable editing.
3. Draw some features.
4. Disable editing or click the "save edits" button to commit your features to the database.

(Of course you need the rights to edit the table.)

Comment: Thanks  underdark.. it was my mistake that i forgot to write that i am doing all these steps programmetically means ... I am customising QGis so that on the click of the button created by me all these features will be added into the postgis vector layer....                                                                                                                                                                            Thanks that you replied for my problem