# How do PostGIS layers in QGIS work?

Tags: postgis, qgis, openstreetmap

I use QGIS 1.4.0 to import a layer which is basically a road network converted from an .osm file to a PostGIS database table by osm2pgrouting.

I have skimmed through the documentation, but I am still not sure:

What happens when I edit features of such a layer in QGIS? Can I somehow write the changes back to the database?

Edit: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14165/how-to-add-features-to-a-postgis-layer-using-quantum-gis) could be the answer, isn't it?

Comment: When you load a postgis layer in and toggle editing - move add, delete features. then toggle editing again you have the option to save the changes - if yes then QGIS writes to the postgis database.

Comment: QGIS 1.7.3 is the stable release with lots of plugins to make our GIS lives a little better/faster. http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What happens when I edit features of such a layer in QGIS?

QGIS logs what you are doing while you are editing.

> Can I somehow write the changes back to the database?

If you disable editing, QGIS will prompt you to save your changes or discard them. That's how you can write the changes back.

PS: And please try a newer version. You won't regret it.