# Add GPS tracks directly to a PostGIS table

Tags: qgis, postgis, gps, tracking

Disclaimer:
I am a total GIS newb and I have a use case I have not seen elsewhere.

Background:
I drive country roads looking for old building, cemeteries, school houses, etc and I record the locations and document them for a website.  I want to use QGIS to keep track of the places in their categories (school, church, cemetery, etc) and also track the roads I have driven as a way to keep duplication of work to a minimum.

I have successfully (I think) setup PostGIS, imported all my items (places + tracks from GPS) from a KML and setup a bluetooth GPS with a small netbook.

I would like to use the built in GPS track maker to record where I have driven and append these lines to a PostGIS table which contains a list of other lines.

I have seen examples of exporting the data to a GPX or SHP file but according to this post ( [How to add features to a PostGIS layer using Quantum GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14165/how-to-add-features-to-a-postgis-layer-using-quantum-gis) ) I should be able to just the line to PostGIS.

According to the documentation I cannot add a GPS Track directly to the PostGIS DB, I must create a new layer and record it there then export / import the data to get it into the DB.  I have had no luck with this up to this point.  I get errors that there are missing columns, once those are added I get other errors about constraints.

How do I accomplish this?   I feel like I'm very close.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up reinstalling the latest Ubuntu 14.04 and found a guide on how to setup PostGIS.

After following these instructions I still had issues importing shapes and features with the SPIT tool.    It turns out the SPIT tool is unsupported and slated for removal and that use of the DB Manager is the way to go.  DB Manager works great!

As for the GPS tracks, once the PostGIS database was reinstalled I was able to add GPS tracks directly to my DB without having to use a new layer and import it later on.

Happy days.